# How much data can I store in IndexDB from a mobile phone using a PWA

Tags: ios, mobile, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I have a PWA designed in Ionic and we are using it to take pictures.  However the requirements is that it needs to work offline so we are storing these pictures in IndexDB.

However I have been unable to track down how much storage we will have access to in IndexDB and am concerned it will only be around 50MB or so.  The the customer potentially wants to store 100 images or more offline and when it gets back to wifi it will start sending up to a remote API.

Is there any information on storage capability for indexDB when a PWA is run on a mobile device either IOS or Android?

I have seen some posts that but mainly talk about storage of the javascript files where this is actual data captured while the app is running.

NOTE:  Individual images will be no more than 2-3MB each in size.

Comment: images are usually cached by the browser cache, do you need to save it again=

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  The application is taking images using the camera of the device it's on and then we need to store those images until we get an internet connection.  My concern is we will only be able to store 4 or 5 and we potentially need to store 100 etc